# how to call function on Ropsten

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, testnets

I deployed a smart contract to Ropsten testnet I want to call its only public function to test it on the network. How can I do such a thing and where I will see the result?

The TxHash is:
0xf321cc101ea280baf13a260bca734cfff73945cf85103a212fc933f3df74e3bd

I wrote it using Solidity on Remix and deployed it using MetaMask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ropsten etherscan for that.

Use the [**write contract** tab on the page for your contract](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x9136e9895d9cb24073f600272dfb78e6d9e2867a#writeContract).

You'll have to login to MetaMask and point it to use the Ropsten network. Then, you can use Etherscan to call the method.